# Constantly Running Service in Java EE

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

How would you implement a constantly running service in Java EE?

What I'm trying to do:

- User1 connects to a service pool; waits for response.
- User2 connects to the same service pool; waits for response.
- Server performs task (matches users) on all Users in the service pool.
- Server returns response to appropriate Users once they have been matched; if User1 matches with User2, User1 receives User2 as a response and User2 receives User1.

I'm not asking how to perform the task (match). I'm asking how to a have this server service run as long as there are Users in the pool?

In Java EE, there seems to be no independently running method support. The only things I can think of are:

- Infinite loop on a separate thread
- Timer Service

I'm wondering if there is another/better way.

Comment: I think a standard controller will listen for HTTP requests as long as the app server is alive.

Comment: Are you talking about `Channel` `Subscription`?

Comment: Right, a Servlet itself will be present as long as an application is alive. But how would that be useful for the question asked? I need an independent constant method. Can't have each session start a new thread and how efficient would be having a thread with an infinite loop?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm not sure. I'm thinking of like an EJB method that performs a task and Sessions connect to waiting for their individual response.

Comment: consider using JMS queue?

Comment: @SergeyPauk From my understanding, that would be good for alerting the Sessions that their response is ready but how would that create a constant running method?

Comment: @chRyNaN JMS queue/topic is a constantly running process in appserver so it could be one of the options I suppose

Comment: Okay, I've never really used JMS so I'll look into it. Can you perform your own logic in a JMS Queue?

Comment: What kind of own logic do you mean? JMS is a transport but data is defined by you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73603/discussion-between-chrynan-and-sergey-pauk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running a process under the hood you're actually right. Can use infinite loop or Timer Service. Take a look at Quartz as well. You just need to register users in some kind of thread safe collection.

For realtime updates you can't be sure that HTTP request will wait long enough. May just timeout. You need to use WebSockets or CometD to abstract publish/subscribe channel. You should use a Java EE server that accepts asynchronous HTTP requests (i.e. suppports Servlet 3)

Comment: With regards to the Timer Service, if the previous call to the method is still being performed when the new timed method call should occur, will this new call wait or will it execute on another thread?

Comment: Just run the service periodically. If you gave some background of the use case we could try follow a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have inded 2 different problems :

1. you want different sessions to interact with each other
2. you want the server to send its response once it could match users

For first part, you could put a specialized bean or object in ServletContext in which sessions will register their users and from where they will get matching users. If you want to allow bidirectionnal exchanges from that time, you can use some kind of pair of buffers where one session writes where the other reads. You should also use a SessionListener to unregister a session as soon as it is closed.

For second part, you must be aware that you cannot hope that a HTTP connection will live as long as you need it. Even if neither the server nor the client have a short timeout, you might go through any other network equipement (proxy, router, ...) that can close it without further notice. IMHO the most robust way would be to have a page that automatically refreshes itself via javascript, a HTTP Refresh header or a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag.